# Finding surface integral of the paraboloid and disk

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Let S be the surface consisting of the paraboloid $y=x^2 + z^2$ with $0 \leq y \leq 1$, and the disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. Let $S$ have an outward orientation. Compute the double integral of $\langle 0,y,-z \rangle\, dS$.

Okay so I know I have to break the disk and paraboloid apart. I have to find their surface integral and then add them together. Looking at the paraboloid I found $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2x$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dz} = 2z$. I'm going to plug this into the equation: the double integral of $$\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{dz}\right)^2 +1}\,dA$$ I'm just having trouble figuring out the domain of integration.

Comment: In three dimensions, $x^2+y^2\leq1$ is not a disk; it is a solid cylinder, because $z$ can be anything. Do you mean your surface $S$ encloses a volume lying inside the cylinder, bounded by the paraboloid? In that case, the flux integral you want is easy: use the divergence theorem. (Hint: the divergence of your vector field $\langle0,y,-z\rangle$ is zero.)

Comment: It should be x^2 + z^2. I thought it was the disk that is the lid of the paraboloid

Comment: The lid of the paraboloid is the disk $x^2+z^2\leq 1$ *in the $y=1$ plane*. Is this a homework problem? Be more careful about how the surface is described. You're also confusing the difference between a surface integral (of a function over a surface) and a flux integral (of a vector field through a surface). The object $\langle0,y,-z\rangle$ is a vector field, not a function.

Comment: It is a problem in the textbook that I was trying in review for the final coming up. The disk equation in the plane y=1 is correct.  Since I have a vector field I have to use the divergence theorem?

Comment: You don't *have* to use the divergence theorem, but the whole point is that the divergence theorem makes this problem trivial. The divergence theorem allows you to turn a flux integral (which in general can be very annoying to compute) into the triple integral of the divergence over the enclosed volume. Here, the divergence is zero. So the integral is zero. The point is that you don't have to do anything but notice that the divergence of your vector field vanishes.